# Failing to Add a Custom Claim to a ClaimsIdentity

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, claims

I'm struggling with adding a custom claim to the custom principal that I created elsewhere. The problem is the ci.Claims contains nothing after call AddClaims. Which is irritating. Any hints?

```
System.Security.Claims.Claim cl = new Claim ( "http://myfoo.com/claims/correlationid", "correlationid");
var identity = principal.Identity;  // this is a custom principal

var ci = new System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity(identity);

var list = new List<Claim>();
list.Add(cl);
ci.AddClaims(list);

principal.AddIdentity(ci);
```